# What is the best image shape/size for indexing images & searching products in Vision API Product Search?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, vision, google-product-search

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#image_sizing) provides information about Image Sizing requirements/best practices for different features.

My question is more specific to Product Search API:

- While creating a product index, what should be the image size of our products for best results?
- While searching products:

  - What should be the size of query images?
  - How should we resize those query images (if larger) for the best match?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [Vision API Product Search: Creating your reference images & indexing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-reference-images), you should provide the image with a bigger resolution as possible, but the total size can't exceed `20MB`. Another parameters are important to a better result. Check the following from the docs.

> **Upload the highest resolution image available.**
> Make sure the size of the file doesn't exceed the maximum size (20MB).

> Consider viewpoints that logically highlight the product and contain relevant visual information. Create reference images that supplement any missing viewpoints. For example, if you only have images of the right shoe in a pair, provide mirrored versions of those files as the left shoe.

> Show the product against a white background. Convert PNGs with transparent backgrounds to a solid background.